# pagedlist performance impacts using c# asp mvc

Tags: pagedlist

i included .NET XPAGED LIST in my project using nuget and is successfully working

the code is

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var query = from p in db.Posts orderby p.ID ascending select p;
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        ViewData["Posts"] = query.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);         
        return View();
    }
```

the main question is that we are using the query to extract all records. then those are skipped and taken by 
.ToPagedList(pageNumber,elementsperpage);

but this creates performance issues.
The query must extract only paged/limited elements like LIMIT(0,5)

do pagedlist limits or i have to create my custom function for paging in asp mvc

Comment: Well, look at the executed SQL statements.